# Android OnTouchListener Does Not Work

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, ontouchlistener

It's simple. The OnTouchListener does not work at all.

I'm fairly certain it's being initialized. I'm using a custom view to draw my UI, and as usual, I'm being impeded by Android's touchy API (pun intended):

```
public class ViewInterface extends View implements OnTouchListener{

public ViewInterface(Context context){
    super(context);

    ...
}

public void update(){
    ...
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        keyboardEnabled = true;
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        keyboardEnabled = false;
        return true;
    default: break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Code for initializing the view in the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_aidan);
    activity = this;

    viewInterface = new ViewInterface(this);
    setContentView(viewInterface);

    initializeSpeechRecognition();
    findMe();

    run.start();
}
```

What am I missing? Upon touching the screen and holding it, keyboardEnabled should be set to true (its just a debug value) - yet it does not do anything. The touch events don't seem to be responding at all.

I've attempted to use the onTouchEvent method built into View with the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        keyboardEnabled = true;
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        keyboardEnabled = false;
        return true;
    default: break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However this did not work either. The touch events are not responding at all - tapping the screen and releasing should be setting keyboardEnabled to false - which it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the `onTouchEvent()` method of the `View` class.

Right now you are simply implementing the `OnTouchListener` interface which should be used in conjunction with the `setOnTouchListener()` method.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Don't forget to call `super` where appropriate!

Alternatively, you could call `setOnTouchListener(this);` somewhere in your code, but that seems redundant.

Comment: I changed the onTouch method into onTouchEvent, and still it's not responding.

Comment: My apologies - I cleaned the project with Eclipse and it solved the problem. Many thanks!